# Unable to add Fine grain access for Elasticsearch service for Cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation, aws-elasticsearch

I am creating `CloudFormation` stack with `Elasticsearch` service, however it fails for `AdvancedSecurityOptions`, which works perfectly fine with `aws es create-elasticsearch-domain`

my `JSON` template snippet is below:

```json
...
"AdvancedOptions": {
    "rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index": true
},
"AdvancedSecurityOptions": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "InternalUserDatabaseEnabled": false,
    "MasterUserOptions": {
    "MasterUserARN": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/role_name"
    }
},
"DomainName": {
    "Ref": "ESDomainName"
}
...
```

I am unable to get this code working, any help related to fine grain access control would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The `AdvancedSecurityOptions` is the latest addition to Amazon Elasticsearch service added [recently](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-elasticsearch-service-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/release-notes.md) as part of [Fine Grained Access Control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html). This is available only via Console, CLI and API for now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However I have to add this option as a part of my cloudformation stack, so any way or workaround via which this can be achieved using cloudformation?

Comment: Nope. Until it is made available by AWS, We will not be able to use it in Cloudformation. You can do a CLI request after successful creation of domain (via Cloudformation) to `update-elasticsearch-domain-config` with the required `--advanced-security-options`.

Comment: Also, I do not see it in their cloudformation [roadmap](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/projects/1) for adding ElasticSearch `AdvancedSecurityOptions`.

Comment: I think that might help out can you explain this update part in your answer. If this works out, then it will be a big help. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I will get back to you in few hours with the results.

Comment: I tried updating, but it is not allowed `An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateElasticsearchDomainConfig operation: You can't modify advanced security options after creating the domain.`

Comment: That is very contradictory, as per the documentation on [update-es-domain-config](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-configuration-api.html#es-configuration-api-actions-updateelasticsearchdomainconfig), this should be possible. Anyway, I will take my alternative solution back, looks like we cannot user cloudformation for now, if `advanced-security-options` are required.

Comment: I agree, I will try doing some more research over this for best approach to get `AdvancedSecurityOptions`.

Comment: Okay, but it looks like this is the only solution for now. Let me know if it can be done in anyother method.

Comment: Sure I will update you, as soon as I get any progress. Thanks for help..

Comment: You can vote on the issue on the cloud formation roadmap https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/384

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the thread is with outdated info, but according to the official AWS documentation on this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticsearch-domain-advancedsecurityoptionsinput.html) it should be possible to use the AdvancedSecurityOptions for Fine Grained Access Control. It even states that it is meant to be used for FGAC at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from DNakevski@ answer above, for FGAC we need to ensure the following three settings in the CFN template are set to true since they serve as [pre-requisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-enabling):

- EncryptionAtRestOptions
- NodeToNodeEncryptionOptions and
- HTTPS.

Further, the important parameter for FGAC in the CFN template is **[AdvancedSecurityOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticsearch-domain-advancedsecurityoptionsinput.html)** and needs to be set to **Enabled: true**

AmazonES/Opendistro-for-ES provides two ways for security with FGAC. One is through using a IAM user as a master-user and other is through having  basic auth.

- If you need to take the IAM way then set the [InternalUserDatabaseEnabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticsearch-domain-advancedsecurityoptionsinput.html#cfn-elasticsearch-domain-advancedsecurityoptionsinput-internaluserdatabaseenabled) to *false*  and only have the parameter *MasterUserARN: "IAM User ARN" under the *MasterUserOptions* field.
- If you need to take the basic auth (username and password) approach set the *InternalUserDatabaseEnabled* to *true* and have the *MasterUserName: "any-name"* and the *MasterUserPassword: "xxx"**  Please have at least one lower case, one upper case, one digit and one special character for the password else the CFN template will rollback. However, the failure message is easily seen on the CFN console under events.

I have a simple working CFN yaml [here](https://github.com/Castern/cfn-amazon-es-fgac) doing the same just in case.